# Java/Scala shutdown hook -noclassdeffounderror

Tags: scala, shutdown-hook

I have a multithreaded Scala application and I have a shutdown hook that calls a shutdown() method on an object.   Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be reliable. Many times it fails to handle SIGINT and throws a NoClassDefFoundError on an anonymous function.

How do I make this shutdown handler more robust?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suggestion: Rather than registering `shutdown()` hook directly, create a `ShutdownManager` object and have it register a `shutdown()` hook. Your application objects add themselves to the `ShutdownManager` which can then call some application object shutdown method, either using a trait or through a function object.

Answer (score 1):

preload all the classes your hook needs with either:

Class.forName("YourObject") or Class clasz = YourObject.class